# How to get Gunicorn to use Python 3 instead of Python 2 (502 Bad Gateway)

Tags: django, python-2.7, python-3.x, nginx, gunicorn

I'm trying to get Gunicorn to use Python3 for a Django app I want to make. I'm using Digital Ocean's Django image to get started. It comes with Django, Gunicorn, and Nginx installed and configured. The default Django project that comes with this image seems to work fine for Python 2.

I've `apt-get`'ed these packages.

- python3
- python3-psycopg2
- python3-dev
- python3-pip

In order to try to avoid any problems, I've also done this.

- pip uninstall django
- pip3 install django

I `rm -rf`'ed the stock project and created a new one with `django-admin.py startproject django_project`. `django-admin.py` uses Python 3 (according to the shebang). Later, I use `python3 manage.py startapp django_app` to create a new app.

At this point, everything works fine. Just like the default app. Then, in `django_app/views.py` I do this and it breaks.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
    # Python 2 and 3 - works fine
    # print('PRINTING')

    # Python 3 only - crashes
    print(1, 2, end=' ')

    return HttpResponse("Hello, world! This is my first view.")
```

The error page says I'm using Python 2.7.6.

Okay, so then I thought I could install Gunicorn through pip for Python 3, so I do this.

- pip uninstall gunicorn
- pip3 install gunicorn

But then I just end up with 502 Bad Gateway. When I do `service gunicorn status`, I get `gunicorn stop/waiting`. I tried `service gunicorn restart`, but it still says `gunicorn stop/waiting`.

I did a `which gunicorn` and it's installed at `/usr/local/bin/gunicorn`. Uhh... I'm not really sure what else I could try. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's probably easier to start afresh. Tutorial at https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-and-configure-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn.

I got it running on a fresh ubuntu 14.04 droplet. Install python3 and django and then simply follow the tutorial. Didn't do the postgres or virtualenv bits though.

Comment: Okay, starting from "Step Nine: Configure Gunicorn" from the Digital Ocean tutorial works. However, I have to start the server manually with `/usr/local/bin/gunicorn -c /home/django/django_project/gunicorn_config.py django_project.wsgi`. Also, this doesn't hook into `service gunicorn`.

Comment: Well, read on a bit: 'This also poses the problem of needing to manually start or restart Gunicorn should your VPS gets rebooted or were it to crash for some reason. To solve this problem, most people use supervisord to manage Gunicorn and start/restart it as needed. Installing and configuring supervisord has been covered in another article which can be found here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-and-manage-supervisor-on-ubuntu-and-debian-vps.'

Comment: It seems like after you uninstall/reinstalled gunicorn, you were able to start using python3 properly, but just in case that was the problem! Try running ```which gunicorn -a```. For me I had to use something like ```/opt/python-3.4.2/bin/gunicorn``` (in CentOS). If this doesn't pertain, then just ignore it!

Answer (score 52):

It seems that there's a package for this called `gunicorn3` (this was tested on ubuntu)

`sudo apt-get install gunicorn3`

then running the following command should work and run gunicorn with python3:

`gunicorn3 --log-level debug --bind 0.0.0.0:30443 server:app`

Comment: This is the only answer that worked on Ubuntu, python 3.6. thanks.

Comment: This was a start, but unfortunately not enough: It starts with Python 3.6, but I need Python 3.7. Want to avoid a virtual env.

Comment: This was a drop-in replacement for gunicorn after starting a droplet with the digitalocean django image. Can't believe they're still using python2 by default.

Answer (score 27):

In case the two links break one day, here's how I got it working.

Starting after executing these instructions.

- `pip uninstall gunicorn`
- `pip3 install gunicorn`

Install `supervisor`, `sudo apt-get install supervisor`.

Next, I needed to make `gunicorn_config.py` in the root of my project directory, which contains this.

```
command = '/usr/local/bin/gunicorn'
pythonpath = '/home/django/django_project'
bind = '127.0.0.1:9000'
workers = 3
user = 'nobody'
```

Then, I created a configuration file for `supervisor`. `vim /etc/supervisor/conf.d/gunicorn.conf`, with these contents.

```
[program:gunicorn]
command=/usr/local/bin/gunicorn -c /home/django/django_project/gunicorn_config.py django_project.wsgi
user=nobody
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stderr_logfile=/var/log/gunicorn3.err.log
stdout_logfile=/var/log/gunicorn3.out.log
```

After that, I did a `supervisorctl reread` and `supervisorctl update` and then it all started working.

You can use `supervisorctl status gunicorn` to check if `gunicorn` is running or not. You can use `supervisorctl restart gunicorn` to restart.

Comment: that worked like a charm :) 
Thanks a lot. after spending hours and hours your solution worked .

Answer (score 10):

my way:

```
virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3 /home/py3env
source /home/py3env/bin/activate
pip3 install gunicorn
/home/py3env/bin/gunicorn -w4 -b0.0.0.0:8000 [projectname].wsgi
```

Comment: This answer is the one that most closely mirrors how to fix the problem in the Digital Ocean tutorial

Comment: Bizarrely, even though `which gunicorn` outputs the gunicorn in my virtualenv, the command `gunicorn myapp` fails due to missing libraries (in other words, it's using the system python and not the virtual env)... but the command `$(which gunicorn) myapp` works fine.

Answer (score 6):

The way I make it happen was to uninstall gunicorn from everywhere:

```
sudo apt-get remove gunicorn
pip uninstall gunicorn
pip3 uninstall gunicorn
```

And then Installing `gunicorn` [from source](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/install.html#from-source).

```
pip3 install git+https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn.git
```

Now everything's running with no problem.

Comment: This is the only answer that worked for me on OSX (skipped the apt-get part) thanks

Answer (score 5):

Wrote the following script to switch to Python 3.4 with DigitalOcean's 14.04 Django image, as I wanted it to be a nice one-step setup... It will be maintained at https://gist.github.com/tr00st/190ab4de62f9b23bea69

The main issue with the setup for me was with gevent, switching to tornado for workers worked fine.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Python 3 Upgrade for Django Droplet
# Will update the "Django on 14.04" Digital Ocean image.
# Run as root.

# Grab psycopg2 and pip
apt-get install python3-pip python3-psycopg2

# Remove the Python 2.7 version of gunicorn, so we can...
pip uninstall gunicorn

# Install the Python 3 version of gunicorn, and a couple of dependencies.
pip3 install gunicorn tornado django
# Sadly, at time of writing, gevent isn't Python 3 compatible... But tornado is!
# So, switch them out with a little sed magic
sed 's/worker_class = '\''gevent'\''/worker_class='\''tornado'\''/' /etc/gunicorn.d/gunicorn.py -i.orig

# Restart gunicorn to make the changes take effect...
service gunicorn restart

# And we're good!
```

Answer (score 3):

I think the best way to do this is go to /usr/local/bin/gunicorn and change first line which is shebang line to #!/usr/bin/python-version

for ex: 
my gunicorn runs with python3.5 interpretor

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.5

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
import sys

from gunicorn.app.wsgiapp import run

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(run())
```

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the `gunicorn` executable, it's just a small python script:

```
$ cat gunicorn
#!/usr/bin/env python

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
import sys

from gunicorn.app.wsgiapp import run

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw?|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(run())
```

The important bit is the `from gunicorn.app.wsgiapp import run` line, which tells you the location of the module responsibe for running your app. If gunicorn is quality code (which it is), you should be able to import that module directly from the command line and run your app.

"Importing the module directly from the command line" means using the [`-m` command line switch](https://docs.python.org/3.6/using/cmdline.html).

> When called with -m module-name, the given module is located on the Python module path and executed as a script.

Using the python of your choice:

```
$ /path/to/your/python -m gunicorn.app.wsgiapp {{ gunicorn command line args go here }} server:app
```

And sure enough it runs!

```
[2017-12-04 02:05:27 +0000] [24] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.7.1
[2017-12-04 02:05:27 +0000] [24] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:5000 (24)
[2017-12-04 02:05:27 +0000] [24] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2017-12-04 02:05:27 +0000] [28] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 28
[2017-12-04 02:05:27 +0000] [29] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 29
```

This behavior is very useful, for example when running gunicorn from somewhere like a Dockerfile.

Answer (score 1):

Install a python3 virtual environment in your project folder

```
$ pipenv --three
```

Then run gunicorn in the activated environment

```
$ gunicorn [PROJECT].wgsi
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a virtual environment

```sh
python3 -m venv .venv
source .venv/bin/activate
pip install gunicorn
```

And, for start gunicorn (if you already have in global)

```sh
.venv/bin/gunicorn # instead of gunicorn
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on Digital Ocean using the droplet "Ubuntu Django on 14.04".

I realized that the 'gevent' worker type was the problem for me when using Python 3. Even though I checked with `python3 -m pip freeze` that 'gevent' was installed, it did not work. I changed it to 'sync' in /etc/gunicorn.d/gunicorn.py:

```
...
worker_class = 'sync'
...
```

I restarted gunicorn:

```
sudo service gunicorn restart
```

I checked the gunicorn service was running by using `service gunicorn status`, and was able to see the welcome to django page by reaching my droplet's ip address.

I hope that works for other people.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how i made it to work for me. I have installed gunicorn both with pip2 and pip3. I need both versions. The default one is gunicorn with pip2.

What I did was I installed gunicorn with virtualenv using pip3 and looked at content of the file gunicorn under bin in the virtualenv folder, that says

```
#!/********/virtualenv/gunicorn3/corto/bin/python3

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
import sys

from gunicorn.app.wsgiapp import run

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw?|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(run())
```

I copied this file and put it elsewhere, then i changed

```
#!/********/virtualenv/gunicorn3/corto/bin/python3
```

to

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
```

Now you can run gunicorn easily like this after getting into the directory that you copied the file gunicorn in

```
python3 gunicorn -c /your_config_file.py class_app:app
```

Note: doing pip3 uninstall gunicorn, followed by pip3 install gunicorn will install gunicron with python3 version (overriding the python2 version) in the dir 'usr/local/bin' (ubuntu) and then you can get the file contents of gunicron there. This will help you avoid using virtualenv.

If this doesnt work first time, do pip3 unistall gunicorn, followed by pip3 install gunicorn.

Happy unicorning ;)