# gunicorn ImportError: No module named django_jalali

Tags: django, python-3.x, gunicorn

I'm running a project using `django`, `nginx` and `gunicorn` which works fine on local machine. When I moved the project to the server and installed everything, I tested the project using `python3 manage.py runserver` and it works fine.

But when I try to run it using `gunicorn`, I ran to this error

> ImportError: No module named django_jalali

The full `gunicorn` command:

```
gunicorn iteachyou.wsgi:application --bind 127.0.0.1:8003
```

I've installed this package and there's no actual issue with it.

There's an almost similar question with this issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39460892/2263683) but it's relative to `wsgi`. Mine is a little weird i guess.

Here's the full traceback:

```
[2018-05-13 00:18:34 +0000] [10893] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.6.0
[2018-05-13 00:18:34 +0000] [10893] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8003 (10893)
[2018-05-13 00:18:34 +0000] [10893] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2018-05-13 00:18:34 +0000] [10897] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10897
[2018-05-13 08:48:34 +0000] [10897] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 557, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 126, in init_process
    self.load_wsgi()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 136, in load_wsgi
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 384, in import_app
    __import__(module)
  File "/var/www/html/iteachyou/iteachyou/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
    application = get_wsgi_application()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 13, in get_wsgi_application
    django.setup(set_prefix=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 94, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named django_jalali
[2018-05-13 08:48:34 +0000] [10897] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10897)
[2018-05-13 00:18:34 +0000] [10893] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
[2018-05-13 00:18:34 +0000] [10893] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
```

In case needed, here's what happened when I installed `pip3 install django-jalali`:

```
Collecting django_jalali
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a4/91/8d4a89be62d22fcb3a1b7c4c953e532e5f519e66cfec2aadbfd030efb413/django-jalali-3.0.2.tar.gz (200kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 204kB 1.2MB/s
Collecting django>=2.0 (from django_jalali)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/23/91/2245462e57798e9251de87c88b2b8f996d10ddcb68206a8a020561ef7bd3/Django-2.0.5-py3-none-any.whl (7.1MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 7.1MB 125kB/s
Collecting jdatetime>=2.0 (from django_jalali)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/97/86/51bb0861c702f790abee2894b30d22aa92375523ba8eef165f65066bfb33/jdatetime-2.0.0.tar.gz
Collecting pytz (from django>=2.0->django_jalali)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/dc/83/15f7833b70d3e067ca91467ca245bae0f6fe56ddc7451aa0dc5606b120f2/pytz-2018.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (510kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 512kB 1.5MB/s
Building wheels for collected packages: django-jalali, jdatetime
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for django-jalali ... done
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/64/5a/7b/239e6e9f55125ebdb1795e7ad5be78fe3a3d8a66156a744ee2
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for jdatetime ... done
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/d6/74/93/28caed166abb6bd4194f1802570987c994f6655bb828242c0e
Successfully built django-jalali jdatetime
Installing collected packages: pytz, django, jdatetime, django-jalali
Successfully installed django-2.0.5 django-jalali-3.0.2 jdatetime-2.0.0 pytz-2018.4
```

**UPDATE**

I've reliazed that `gunicorn` is using `python2.7`.

I tried uninstall and then install it again. But it's still using `python2.7`.

How do I make it to use `python3` instead?

**UPDATE 2**

I tried uninstalling django 2 and then gunicorn and installing everything from fresh. But gunicorn still uses python2.7.

Comment: Make sure you have `django_jalali` in your `INSTALLED_APPS` settings

Comment: @Satendra I do. the project runs fine in local machine or with `manage.py runserver` on the server. I found the issue (update 1). But I can't fix it

Comment: for making your project run with python3, create virtualenv with python3. `virtualenv -p python3 envname`

Comment: Hope this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23928213/how-to-get-gunicorn-to-use-python-3-instead-of-python-2-502-bad-gateway) will help

Comment: @Satendra Thanks. But already have tried all the solutions there. No help.

Comment: @Satendra Also I tried `virtualenv -p python3 envname`. But even there, gunicorn is using `python2.7`

Comment: have you installed all requirements after creating new env with python3

Comment: @Satendra Yes. Everything is installed and ready.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got it fix by Installing `gunicorn` [from source](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/install.html#from-source).

```
pip3 install git+https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn.git
```

And now `gunicorn` is using `python3`