# nginx with gunicorn and django on centos 7

Tags: django, nginx, centos7, gunicorn

I'm trying to make my nginx and gunicorn start working... but seemingly trying everything I could do, fails...

If I do:

```
systemctl restart nginx
systemctl status nginx
```

It shows green, and it works...
If I do:

```
systemctl start gunicorn.socket
systemctl status gunicorn.socket -l
```

It shows green and works fine...
But if I do:

```
systemctl start gunicorn.service
systemctl status gunicorn.service -l
```

it shows me the following message:

```
gunicorn.service - gunicorn daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2020-09-10 14:17:23 UTC; 15min ago
  Process: 22145 ExecStart=/home/scorg/pro/sc_project/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/scorg/pro/projects/sc/sc.sock sc.wsgi:application (code=exited, status=3)
 Main PID: 22145 (code=exited, status=3)

Sep 10 14:17:23 gunicorn[22145]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
Sep 10 14:17:23  gunicorn[22145]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
Sep 10 14:17:23  gunicorn[22145]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
Sep 10 14:17:23 : ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sc'
Sep 10 14:17:23 : [2020-09-10 14:17:23 +0000] [22152] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 22152)
Sep 10 14:17:23 : [2020-09-10 14:17:23 +0000] [22145] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
Sep 10 14:17:23 : [2020-09-10 14:17:23 +0000] [22145] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
Sep 10 14:17:23 : gunicorn.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=3/NOTIMPLEMENTED
Sep 10 14:17:23 : Unit gunicorn.service entered failed state.
Sep 10 14:17:23 : gunicorn.service failed.
```

I kind of understand it is bind problem and I followed this question:
[Gunicorn, no module named 'myproject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39460892/gunicorn-no-module-named-myproject)

But whatever module I try to bind with the following command, it just doesn't work:

```
gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 wsgi:application
```

I tried wsgi, sc.wsgi, sc/wsgi, /whole_path/wsgi It's just always the same result... mofule not found...

my gunicorn.service looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
Requires=gunicorn.socket
After=network.target

[Service]
User=root
#scorg
Group=root
#www-data
Environment=SECRET_KEY=secret
WorkingDirectory=/home/scorg/pro/projects/sc/sc
ExecStart=/home/scorg/pro/sc_project/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/scorg/pro/projects/sc/sc.sock  sc.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The structure is as following:

```
sc
├── manage.py
├── sc
│   ├── asgi.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
└── sc_site
    ├── admin.py
    ├── apps.py
    ├── forms.py
    ├── models.py
    ├── __pycache__
    ├── static
    │   ├── admin
    │   ├── css
    │             
    ├── templates
    ├── urls.py
    └── views.py
```

I'm in the world of pain at the time. I was struggling with Apache ... I'm noob at centos 7/ linux servers management... Apparently I am stuck... If I forgot to give some extra information... Please let me know, I will happily make an update...

Also I did make sure that I set up gunicorn... So it is on the system and works...:

```
yum install python-gunicorn
```

**Update**
After all fight with the options for gunicorn, it is using python 2.7. I have python 3.8.5... I tried to follow this tutorial [How to get Gunicorn to use Python 3 instead of Python 2 (502 Bad Gateway)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23928213/how-to-get-gunicorn-to-use-python-3-instead-of-python-2-502-bad-gateway) , but so far I cannot figure out completely what to do... I did everything and it's still using python2.7... Interesting thing:

I tried to delete gunicorn... pip uninstall guncorn
And system tells me that I don't have gunicorn, same story with pip3...
I installed gunicorn with pip3 install gunicorn, but it still trying to use python2.7:

```
[[/home/scorg/pro]]# sc_project/bin/gunicorn_start
Starting scorg_app as root
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
PYTHONPATH
2020-09-14 11:15:43 [4865] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 18.0
2020-09-14 11:15:43 [4865] [DEBUG] Arbiter booted
2020-09-14 11:15:43 [4865] [INFO] Listening at: unix:/home/scorg/pro/run/gunicorn.sock (4865)
2020-09-14 11:15:43 [4865] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2020-09-14 11:15:43 [4871] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 4871
2020-09-14 11:15:43 [4871] [ERROR] Exception in worker process:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 495,in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line106, in init_process
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 114, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 62, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 49, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 354, inimport_app
    __import__(module)
ImportError: No module named projects.sc.sc.wsgi
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 495,in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line106, in init_process
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 114, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 62, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 49, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 354, inimport_app
    __import__(module)
ImportError: No module named projects.scrap.scrap.wsgi
2020-09-14 11:15:43 [4871] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 4871)
2020-09-14 11:15:43 [4872] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 4872
2020-09-14 11:15:43 [4872] [ERROR] Exception in worker process:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 495,in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line106, in init_process
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 114, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 62, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 49, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 354, inimport_app
    __import__(module)
ImportError: No module named projects.sc.sc.wsgi
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 495,in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line106, in init_process
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 114, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 62, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 49, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 354, inimport_app
    __import__(module)
ImportError: No module named projects.sc.sc.wsgi
2020-09-14 11:15:43 [4872] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 4872)
2020-09-14 11:15:43 [4873] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 4873
2020-09-14 11:15:43 [4873] [ERROR] Exception in worker process:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 495,in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line106, in init_process
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 114, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 62, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 49, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 354, inimport_app
    __import__(module)
ImportError: No module named projects.scrap.scrap.wsgi
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 495,in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line106, in init_process
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 114, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 62, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 49, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 354, inimport_app
    __import__(module)
ImportError: No module named projects.sc.sc.wsgi
2020-09-14 11:15:43 [4873] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 4873)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/bin/gunicorn", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('gunicorn==18.0', 'console_scripts', 'gunicorn')()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 71, in run
    WSGIApplication("%(prog)s [OPTIONS] [APP_MODULE]").run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 143, in run
    Arbiter(self).run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 203,in run
    self.halt(reason=inst.reason, exit_status=inst.exit_status)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 298,in halt
    self.stop()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 341,in stop
    self.reap_workers()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 452,in reap_workers
    raise HaltServer(reason, self.WORKER_BOOT_ERROR)
gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>
```

But when I try uninstall gunicorn, it tried to uninstall gunicorn for python3.8... While I'm trying to run gunicorn it runs for python2.7... Unbelievable...

```
[ [/home/scorg/pro]]# pip uninstall gunicorn
Found existing installation: gunicorn 20.0.4
Uninstalling gunicorn-20.0.4:
  Would remove:
    /usr/local/bin/gunicorn
    /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn-20.0.4.dist-info/*
    /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/*
Proceed (y/n)? y
  Successfully uninstalled gunicorn-20.0.4
```

Comment: check out this tutorial, this is very helpful and will solve your issue: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: Thank you... I will do it... I hope it will be different one, because I checked thoroughly with about 5 other tutorials... and read many posts on the stackoverflow,fixing mistakes and trying to fix this particular one. Thank you for the advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to add "--chdir " in ExecStart?

like

ExecStart=/home/scorg/pro/sc_project/bin/gunicorn --chdir /home/scorg/pro/projects/sc/sc --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/scorg/pro/projects/sc/sc.sock  sc.wsgi:application

Comment: gunicorn[16327]: Error: can't chdir to '/home/scorg/pro/projects/sc/sc'

Comment: I found mistake in the directory I wrote... I tried it again

Comment: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sc'

Comment: I thought earlier, I have wsgi module... Its name is not sc.wsgi... So I tried only wsgi in the name... But it is the same story and the same fault...

Comment: Thank you for your advices!

Comment: are you using virtualenv?

Comment: Yes, I do... But I tried it with switched on virtual environment too. I will try it again... May be I missed something... And it will work this time.

Comment: Hello, Wonderful stranger! I'm still struggling! :)) I am running between uwsgi and gunicorn... I was struggling today for several hours to start my gunicorn.service on my virtual machine... And after some time I tried this advice from you... And gunicorn started to work. So I now have some hope! Thank you so much for the help!!!

Comment: I made it work on my virtual machine... Finally... I had 1 billion mistakes :), but still managed to start it up...

Answer (score 1):

If you have virtualenv follow this steps:

1. create guncorn.conf config file

ex: touch /opt/yourproject/gunicorn.conf

> ```
>  import multiprocessing
>  workers = multiprocessing.cpu_count()*2+1
>  bind='unix:/var/run/gunicorn.sock'
>  logfile="/var/log/guni.log"
>  errorlog = '-'
>  loglevel = 'info'
>  accesslog = '-'
>  timeout=120
>  proc_name = "yourproject"
>  user="root"
>  group="root"
> ```

2. create "gunicorn_start" file.
   ex: touch /opt/yourproject/gunicorn_start

> ```
>  #!/bin/bash 
>  NAME="yourproject" 
>  DJANGODIR= **** #ex: /home/yourproject/  #change this
>  ENVBIN=/yourvirtualenvdir/bin/   
>  SOCKFILE=/var/run/gunicorn.sock
>  USER=root 
>  GROUP=root 
>  NUM_WORKERS=5 #change this 
>  DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE= ****   #ex: yourproject.settigns.main #change this
>  DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE=****.wsgi  #ex: yourproject.wsgi #change this
>  TIMEOUT=120 
>  echo "Starting $NAME as `whoami`" 
>  ## Activate the virtual environment
>  cd $DJANGODIR 
>  source $ENVBIN/activate 
>  cd $DJANGODIR 
>  export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=$DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE 
>  export PYTHONPATH=$DJANGODIR:$PYTHONPATH 
>  ## Create the run directory if it doesn't exist
>  RUNDIR=$(dirname $SOCKFILE) 
>  test -d $RUNDIR || mkdir -p $RUNDIR
>  ## Start your Django Unicorn
>  ## Programs meant to be run under supervisor should not daemonize themselves (do not use --daemon)
>  exec $ENVBIN/gunicorn ${DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE}:application -c=/opt/yourproject/gunicorn.conf
> ```

3. create service

> ```
> [Unit]
> Description=My Python Service
>
> [Service]
> User=root
> Restart=always
> Type=simple
> WorkingDirectory=/opt/yourproject/ 
> ExecStart=/usr/bin/sh gunicorn_start
>
> [Install] WantedBy=multi-user.target
> ```

Comment: Thank you for the help! I will try it. Also I was talking to the person who has experience in Ubuntu for more than 10 years, he told me that it also could be broken version of Centos installed on the server... He advised me to try on my system with Centos first and if the app runs, then just reinstall centos and do the same install as on the virtual centos...

Comment: Hello! You pushed me into the right direction. Thank you. But I'm still struggling with some settings... I don't know if I e[plain it right, but I will try... If you don't mind and if you can, can you please let me know if I'm right or not:

Comment: my main directory is standard after installing django and it is somehow forked. What do I mean... 1. source /pro/sc_project/bin/activate is in one directory, while django_settings_module is in pro/projects/sc/settings.py, while django_wsgi_module is in pro/projects/sc/sc/wsgi

Comment: should I? : djangodir=/home/scorg/pro/    source ..sc_project/bin/activate    django_settings_module=projects.sc.settings    django_wsgi_module=projects.sc.sc.wsgi         To me that makes sense... Do you thing to gunicorn it will makes sense?

Comment: if your djangodir is /home/scorg/pro/ and django_settings_module=projects.sc.settings,  django_wsgi_module=projects.sc.sc.wsgi , that means for gunicorn that  settings.py location is /home/scorg/pro/projects/sc/settings.py and wsg_module location is /home/scorg/pro/projects/sc/sc/wsgi.py.